# Having CSS flex box within a flex box child elements in HTML 5

Tags: html, css

I have a panel which uses display: flex to have a fixed size header and then a content div filling the rest of the panels height (the panel could be any height). That works fine.

Inside the content div I want the same thing but in reverse. This time however, the content div contains a bunch of content (let's say text for simplicity). This content div should behave as follows:

It should expand to fill the parent div if the content is small
It should overflow scroll if the content is too big
Currently I can't figure out how to do either.

Here is a demonstration of the problem:

Comment: add some code...Without code probably no one can understand your problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the examples below. Hope these examples helps you.

```css
.parent {
height: 200px;
width: 150px;
background-color: lightblue;
padding: 10px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
justify-content: space-between;
overflow-y: auto;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.child{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: white;
  min-height: 25%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
</div>
```